# Apache server running at nearly 100%

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have just moved our web apps to a self hosted site on digital ocean, vs our previous web host. The instance is getting hammered by rpm's according to New Relic but we are seeing very few page views. Throughput RPM's are around the 400rpm stage where as we only have about 1 page view per minute.

When i look at the access log it is getting hammered with what i am guessing is spambots, trying to access the non existant downloads folder. Its causing my CPU to run at 95%, even though nothing is actually happening.

How can i stop this spamming access??
So far i have created a downloads folder and put a Deny All in a htaccess file in it. That appeared to cool things down but now its getting worse again (hence the desperate post)

Comment: Using IPTABLES right. 
We have started doing that, but are worried about blocking well meaning traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find a pattern of malevolent requests and restrict the IP they are coming from.
2. Require a hashed headrt to be provided for each request to verify the identity of the person/group wanting access.
3. Restrict more than N downloads to any IP over M time threshold.
4. Distribute traffic load via DNS proxying to multiple hosts/web servers.
5. Switch to NGINX.  NGINX is more performant than Apache in most cases with "high-levels" of requests.  See Digital Ocean's article --> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-vs-nginx-practical-considerations.
6. Make sure your firewall employs a whitelist of hosts/ports.  NOT *

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `tables` to `drop` any connection from the spam bot ip address.

Find which ips are connected to your apache server:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

You should get something like:

```
  20 49.237.134.0
  10 31.187.6.0
  15 166.137.246.0
```

Once you find the bot ip addresses (probably the ones with higher number of connections), use `iptables` to `DROP` further connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 49.237.134.0 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -s 31.187.6.0 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -s 166.137.246.0 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP
```

---

Note:

Make **sure** you're not dropping connections from search engine bots like google, yahoo, etc...
You can use [www.infobyip.com](http://www.infobyip.com) to get detailed information about a specific ip address.